# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Like Query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to query categories where product tags is equal to user selected tags in filter bar ,
Here is the query what I have tried so far :

```
$categories = Category::with('products');

// selected tags is array which contain tags
if (! empty($selectedTags)) {
    foreach ($categories->get() as $category) {
        $categories = $category->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($selectedTags) {
            foreach ($selectedTags as $tag) {
                $query->where('tags','LIKE','%'.$tag.'%');
            }
        });
    }
}

$categories = $categories->distinct()->paginate(3);
```

On First attempt means when I select single checkbox of tag it is working fine but not multiple selected checkboxes

Please note that tags column in product table is comma separated values that's why I am trying to access it via like query .

Comment: first thing is you don't need to get all the categories and eager load products as you are not doing anything with them ... you are constantly reassigning `$categories` in your loop (to a new builder instance each time) not building up a query on a single builder instance ... and `tags` should be another table linking to `products` with a many to many relationship (ideally)

Comment: So should I just query Category::query(); like this ?

Comment: `Category::whereHas('products', ...)->paginate(3);` ... also you will probably need to use an 'OR' in your query there

Comment: I will do more filteration stuff after tags so I will create collection in last in schools

Answer (score 0):

You just need to be adding to the same builder you started to build the query with instead of using a new builder every iteration of the loop:

```
$categories = Category::with('products');

if ($selectedTags) {
    $categories->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($selectedTags) {
        foreach ($selectedTags as $tag) {
            $query->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%'. $tag .'%');
        }
    });
}

$categories = $categories->distinct()->paginate(3);
```

Comment: Its returning all data .